# Seeking term for step-grandmother's brother

Tags: kinship-terminology, non-blood-relative

I'm trying to wrap my head around this, but I have no clue what's right.  Maybe it would just be classified as "no relation", but that seems wrong to me.

The situation is that you have a grandfather, who remarries.  I think that would be a step-grandmother, but I'm not even confident about that.  It seems like a step-grandmother would actually imply that you have a step-mother or step-father, and it was *their* grandmother.

But if that's right, then would the "step-grandmother's" brother be called a "step-great-uncle", but that doesn't really capture the relationship either.

Can anyone supply an appropriate term?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Steve Morse relationship calculator](http://stevemorse.org/relation/calculator.html) suggests step-great-uncle is correct.

To see this click the buttons on that website in this order:

1. `father` or `mother` (you do not say if it is a paternal or maternal grandfather)
2. `father`
3. `wife`
4. `brother`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that the gentleman in question be called Fred or George or whatever else his given name might be.

Any attempt to construct a family relationship is doomed to failure for the simple reason that he is **not related to you**. Conduct a thought experiment in which George dies intestate and is found to have a hidden multi-million dollar fortune. What share would you expect to receive?

The only answer that would make sense (to anyone other than genealogists arguing over the number of ancestors able to balance on the head of pin) is that he is the brother-in-law of your grandfather. End of story.