# Is there a resource for easily determining relationships between two relatives?

Tags: kinship-terminology

In the English language, there are many words for relationships between two relatives. For instance, my father's brother is my "uncle", the daughter of my father's brother is my "first cousin", the wife of my father's brother is my "cousin-in-law" and so on.

I remember once seeing an online resource that would allow you to plug in the two relatives and spit out their relationship. It even included all of those completely confusing "blah blah  twice removed" relationships. I have no idea where that link is any more and I've been looking for one such link ever since.

Does anyone know of a resource for easily determining relationships between two relatives in the way I have described?

These previous questions have elements of what I'm looking for, but not completely:

[With generations of multiple marriages and step children, how is this family relationship described?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1510/with-generations-of-multiple-marriages-and-step-children-how-is-this-family-rel)

[How do I determine a relationship with a cousin?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/218/how-do-i-determine-a-relationship-with-a-cousin)

Comment: Gramps (the software) has a fairly good relationship calculator, for English and a bunch of other languages. Probably not what you're looking for, though. :)

Comment: To add to the list below, Family Tree Maker (Ancestry.com) includes a relationship calculator that will do what you want, there are a few old and free versions kicking around the Ancestry site eg.  http://c.ancestry.com/Affiliate/Knowledgebase/Images/Ftm/ftm2005se.exe

Answer (score 4):

The site you are referring to may well be [Steve Morse's Relationship Calculator](http://stevemorse.org/relation/calculator.html) which has been used recently to answer two questions here:

- [Determining name for family relationship that involves a step daughter?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/5284/determining-name-for-family-relationship-that-involves-a-step-daughter)
- [What would a step-grandmother's(?) brother be called?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/5273/what-would-a-step-grandmothers-brother-be-called)

Comment: It isn't the site I was thinking of -- the one I had in mind was laid out as a family tree with blanks allowing you to type in the relative's name in the right space and then you click a button that would reveal the relationship -- but this is a great one to add to my collection. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If both relatives have profiles on [WikiTree](http://www.wikitree.com), there is a "Relationship Finder" tool that will tell you the (blood) relationship between them: [http://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Special:Relationship](http://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Special%3aRelationship)

Comment: In my case, this isn't going to be used by any relatives. It's strictly for me, in those cases where I want to know how someone else is related to me (answering questions like "is she my second cousin, or is she my first cousin once removed?"). But this is yet another useful resource, for which I thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Could you have been thinking of [Kinship Calculator](http://www.thinkgenealogy.com/kincalc/) by Mark Tucker? It is a simple online interactive diagram that allows you to determine the relationships of two people knowing the relationship of each to a common ancestor.

However it does not have spousal relationships (e.g. cousin-in-law).

Comment: Not exactly; what I was thinking of was more like a tree structure. However, yet another useful resource to add to the collection, for which I thank you!